# Touchpad corners not clickable on ASUS Zenbook Prime UX32VD?

Tags: laptop, touchpad, ultrabook

I recently got an ASUS Zenbook Prime UX32VD, but I'm having trouble getting used to the touchpad.

When I need to click on the touchpad, I tend to move my finger to the lower corner of the touchpad. But the lower corners on this touchpad are not clickable. The pad simply doesn't depress in the corners.

Close to the edges, clicking is possible, but requires significantly more force, than the easy press needed elsewhere. About 1,5 cm from the sides, I can click with just a soft press.

I could properly get used to it over time, but clicking the corners is what feel natural to me, and what I do, if I don't actively think about where I press.

Is this "by design" on this particular ultrabook or is my ultrabook perhaps not assembled properly?

Are the corners of other models/generation of the Zenbook Prime series clickable?

Thanks!

Update:
To partly answer my last question; the touchpad on the UX31 is perfectly clickable, using a minimum amount of force. Just visited a friend that has this one.

Comment: "You've earned the "Tumbleweed" badge" :) - Anyone wants to take a poke at this?

Comment: FWIW, I've sent the ultrabook back for repair (not just because of this). Time will tell if they think it's a fault...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sent the laptop back, reporting the touchpad assembly as bad.

Got it back and I can now press the corners :-).